# JayData: Trying to insert with a 1 to Many, getting DEFAULT ERROR CALLBACK

Tags: javascript, sqlite, jaydata

I have stripped down my application and database context to the simplest bits.  I have two tables, Maps and Markers.  Many Markers exist for each map.  With an existing Map, I can't seem to insert new Markers; I am getting the default error callback.

Tracing through the jaydata.js, I am getting an error in the SqLiteProvider.js file, in the `exec` function.  It is an SQL failure, and is attempting to insert the Map (with the primary key set) into the table, which fails.  What am I doing wrong?

My Context:

```
$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Marker", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Left: { type: "int", required: true },
    Top: { type: "int", required: true },
    Color: { type: "string", required: true },
    Name: { type: "string", required: true },
    Map: { type: "$org.types.Map", inverseProperty: "Markers" }
});


$data.Entity.extend("$org.types.Map", {
    Id: { type: "int", key: true, computed: true },
    Title: { type: "string", required: true },
    Src: { type: "string", required: true },
    Height: { type: "int", required: true },
    Width: { type: "int", required: true },
    Markers: { type: "Array", elementType: "$org.types.Marker", inverseProperty: "Map" }
});

$data.EntityContext.extend("$org.types.OrgContext", {
    Maps: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Map },
    Markers: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: $org.types.Marker },
 });

var DB = new $org.types.OrgContext({ name: "webSql", databaseName: "Testing"});
```

My test code:

```
DB.Maps.single( function (map) { return map.Id == 1; }, {}, function(map) {
        var marker = new $org.types.Marker({
            Left: 250,
            Top: 350,
            Color: 'green',
            Name: 'Example',
            Map: map});

        DB.Markers.add(marker);
        DB.saveChanges(function() {
            alert(marker.Id);
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example doesn't insert the map object. This is not a problem if you already have it.

There is a general problem, which is forgotten many times: the `context.onReady()` should be used before accessing data with the provider.

This won't solve the problem per se, there is one line should be added before saving the ne marker object:

```
DB.Maps.attach(map);
```

This is necessary to move the object to the scope of the context and set the entityState property of the map to $data.EntityState.Unchanged. If you read an entity from the DB, the entityState will be unknown, and the provider tries to save it as a new record. Trying to saving the map entity as a new record caused an SQL error, because there was an existing record with ID=1.

The updated code looks like bellow:

```
var DB = new $org.types.OrgContext({ name: "webSql", databaseName: "Testing" });

        DB.onReady(function () {
            DB.Maps.single(function (map) { return map.Id == 1; }, {}, function (map) {
                DB.Maps.attach(map); //this sets map.entityState = $data.EntityState.Unchanged;
                var marker = new $org.types.Marker({
                    Left: 250,
                    Top: 350,
                    Color: 'green',
                    Name: 'Example',
                    Map: map
                });
                DB.Markers.add(marker);
                DB.saveChanges(function () {
                    alert(marker.Id)
                });
            });
        });
```

**UPDATE**: if you save a new Maker with a new Map entity, there is no need to attach, and your code needs only the DB.onReady()

Comment: Thanks; the critical piece was the `attach()`.  Thanks as well for the explanation of the entityState property - that makes total sense.  I would add that the documentation is pretty light on the `context.onReady()` - I have been scouring JayData documentation for a few weeks now and this is the first that I have read about that!

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I must totally agree with you on the documentation and we began to improve this on the website.

Comment: That's great.  I think JayData is a really useful ORM, and am enjoying using it.

Comment: @Robesz everybody is suffering with the docs and few examples of jaydata usage. This is a powerful tool but people have to know how to use it. BTW, please look at my most recent question about it. I'm in a need of some directions in jay data.. Thank you.

Comment: @DontVodeMeDown: you can find more examples here: http://jaydata.org/examples . This is the first time I hear everybody's suffer with the docs, please pose specific questions and the team will help you.